# Differentiate Var = new List<Variable>(); and public Variable Var{ get; set; }

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain what is the difference between:

```
Var1 = new List<Variable>();
```

and

```
public Variable Var1{ get; set; }
```

where

```
public class Variable 
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In what way they differ or are they the same?

Any help is great. Thanks.

Comment: `Var` cannot be used while declaring a List

Comment: See the difference between fields and properties in C#.

Comment: You have changed the question :P

Comment: where would the compiler find `Var1` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `List<Variable> Var1 = new List<Variable>();`

That was declaring `Var1` as a collection of `Variable` object. So Var1 would hold list of `Variable`

```
Var1.Add(new Variable());
Var1.Add(new Variable());
Var1.Add(new Variable());
```

Now we have 3 items in Var1

2) `public Variable Var1{ get; set; }`

That was declaring Var1 as a property of a class and can only take one value at a time

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Variable Var1{ get; set; }
}

MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Var1 = v; //where v is an instance of Variable class
//or
Variable v = c.Var1; //returns an Instance of Variable which is a property of c
```

Answer (score 0):

var is datatype provided by .NET, Var is an implicit type. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. It aliases any type in the C# programming language. The aliased type is determined by the C# compiler. This has no performance penalty. Var is excellent syntactic sugar.

e.g.

```
var str = "Hello World";
```

is compiled as

```
string str = "Hello World";
```

Whereas Variable here is a custom Class and has nothing to do with var of C# .NET. They are not related in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`var = new List<Variable>();`

This will create a list of `Variable`, if your concern is with keyword `var` then its simply tells the compiler that i know the datatype and so do you so just carry on.

`Variable Var1{get;set;}` is the property, this allows you to set or get the Members of `Variable`

for e.g

```
Var1 = new Variable{
Var1.Value = "abc" // setter;
}
```

Or

```
return Var1.Value // getter;
```

Comment: OK, what about the public Variable Var1{ get; set; } what does it create or return?